# Filtering a collection of IO's: List[IO[Page]] scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s, cats-effect

I am refactoring a scala http4s application to remove some pesky side effects causing my app to block. I'm replacing .unsafeRunSync with cats.effect.IO. The problem is as follows:

I have 2 lists: alreadyAccessible: IO[List[Page]] and pages: List[Page]
I need to filter out the pages that are not contained in alreadyAccessible.
Then map over the resulting list to "grant Access" in the database to these pages. (e.g. call another method that hits the database and returns an IO[Page].

```
    val addable: List[Page] = pages.filter(p => !alreadyAccessible.contains(p))
    val added: List[Page] = addable.map((p: Page) => {
      pageModel.grantAccess(roleLst.head.id, p.id) match {
        case Right(p) => p
      }
    })
```

This is close to what I want; However, it does not work because filter requires a function that returns a Boolean but alreadyAccessible is of type IO[List[Page]] which precludes you from removing anything from the IO monad. I understand you can't remove data from the IO so maybe transform it:

```
val added: List[IO[Page]] = for(page <- pages) {
val granted = alreadyAccessible.flatMap((aa: List[Page]) => {
        if (!aa.contains(page))
           pageModel.grantAccess(roleLst.head.id, page.id) match { case Right(p) => p }
        else null
      })
    } yield granted
```

this unfortunately does not work with the following error:

```
Error:(62, 7) ';' expected but 'yield' found.
    } yield granted
```

I think because I am somehow mistreating the for comprehension syntax, I just don't understand why I cannot do what I'm doing.

I know there must be a straight forward solution to such a problem, so any input or advice is greatly appreciates. Thank you for your time in reading this!

Answer (score 3):

`granted` is going to be an `IO[List[Page]]`. There's no particular point in having `IO` *inside* anything else unless you truly are going to treat the *actions* like values and reorder them/filter them etc.

```
val granted: IO[List[Page]] = for {
```

How do you compute it? Well, the first step is to execute `alreadyAccessible` to get the actual list. In fact, `alreadyAccessible` is misnamed. It is not the list of accessible pages; it is an action that gets the list of accessible pages. I would recommend you rename it `getAlreadyAccessible`.

```
    alreadyAccessible <- getAlreadyAccessible
```

Then you filter `pages` with it

```
    val required = pages.filterNot(alreadyAccessible.contains)
```

Now, I cannot decipher what you're doing to these pages. I'm just going to assume you have some kind of function `grantAccess: Page => IO[Page]`. If you map this function over `required`, you will get a `List[IO[Page]]`, which is not desirable. Instead, we should `traverse` with `grantAccess`, which will produce a `IO[List[Page]]` that executes each `IO[Page]` and then assembles all the results into a `List[Page]`.

```
    granted <- required.traverse(grantAccess)
```

And we're done

```
} yield granted
```

Comment: Why is List[IO[Page]] not desirable? I'm guessing if each page was wrapped in IO the code would be more complex to access it instead of when you wrap the collection in IO?

Comment: *You can't "wrap" a `Page` in `IO`!* An `IO[Page]` is an action that *produces* a page. Think of `IO[T]` as a side-effecting `() => T`. Do you *really* want a list of unexecuted actions? Note that if you have a `List[IO[Page]]`, you can't even access the same "`Page`" twice, since you'd end up *executing* it twice. Also, it's not possible to get a `List[IO[Page]]` anyway. You're starting with an `IO[_]` value any; any result *will* be wrapped with `IO` on the outside. The use of `traverse` is just saving you from `IO[List[IO[Page]]]`.